# Power BI Desktop Scheduled Refresh

Tags: powerbi

I know it is possible to adhoc refresh the data on power bi desktop but unlike on power bi online I am unable to find a way of creating a scheduled refresh. I have looked into personal gateways but unable to find a suitable solution. I want the data to be refreshed daily and this data is coming from a postgres database in Amazon Web Service where the data is updated daily.

Comment: you can find all necessari information in this linked page:
[Keep your dashboards and reports up-to-date with your on-premises data sources](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI desktop(local) have only manual refresh, scheduler is not available in desktop power bi when you want to implement scheduler then follow this link

1. [how-to-configure-schedule-refresh-in-power-bi-reports](https://www.loginworks.com/blogs/how-to-configure-schedule-refresh-in-power-bi-reports/)

when you established a connection using the database and create report and publish on app power bi from power bi desktop after that apply scheduler then it will reflect data changes on every refresh.

Cheers.